# How can I get a lovely precipitate sign?

Tags: fonts, chemmacros

I like the precipitate sign on the P20 of [`chemformula` official documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/chemformula). But I can only get like this on my own computer by the example code:

[image: Ugly sign]

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe: `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` Please provide an image of what you want and of what you have with the code you needed to get there in your post. Try to leave external links from your post, as we can not be sure where they lead to. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi The package works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. The optional `libertine` can be left away, I guess. Just copied that line of code from Clemen's chemformula_en.tex.  The loading of this package will possibly change other symbols as well. Just read its manual. The arrow you were showing above was from Latin Modern which is default. Just fyi.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi care to answer?

Answer (score 2):

The author of the `chemformula` package loads the package `newtextmath` in his documentation which changes the arrows (and most probably other symbols). Your current result is an arrow from the font Latin Modern which is the default for LaTeX. Please see my MWE for the desired version. (For future post please always post such an MWE which makes it easier for us. Please change the title of your post to something more telling than no! Thanks)

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}    
\ch{v}\ch{^}
\end{document}
```